# java imagej dialog don't show

Tags: java, imagej

Hello that is very curious but in a macro when I type:

```
run("my plugin");
```

it's working the dialog is showing but and that is my problem when I type

```
run("my plugin", "5");
```

For example, my dialog don't appear anymore and I find pretty curious and that's a problem because I wanted to pass argument to my plugin and get it via `Macro.getoptions()` in my plugin code.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, you are mixing two methods `run(String arg)` method from [`ij.plugin.Plugin`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/plugin/PlugIn.html) and the ImageJ macro command [`run("command"\[, "options"\])`](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#run), from [`IJ.run(String command, String options)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/IJ.html#run%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

If you read carefully the documentation of [`ij.plugin.Plugin#run(String arg)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/plugin/PlugIn.html#run%28java.lang.String%29), it states:

> This method is called when the plugin is loaded. 'arg', which may be blank, is the argument specified for this plugin in IJ_Props.txt.

In this case, `arg` is an optional argument that you can use in [`IJ_Props.txt`](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/download/IJ_Props.txt) or in the [`plugins.config`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/jar-demo.html) file of your plugin to assign different menu commands to different functions of your plug-in (see also the [excellent documentation on the Fiji wiki](http://fiji.sc/Introduction_into_Developing_Plugins)).

To make use of the `options` parameter when running your plugin from macro code, you should use a [`GenericDialog`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/gui/GenericDialog.html) to get the options, or (as you apparently learned the hard way) use the helper function [`Macro.getOptions()`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/Macro.html).